# Conditional JSON schema returns too much errors when simulating wrong JSON file

Tags: json, jsonschema

First of, I already read many threads and how-tos regarding this subject and didn't find an answer that helped me (inclufing the https://json-schema.org/ reference).

I have a complex JSON schema that I will simplify here but the logic remains the same. It involves conditional determination of a specific property based on the value of another property.

The simplified schema here:

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
  "$ref": "#/definitions/Main",
  "definitions": {
    "Main": {
      "title": "Main",
      "type": "object",
      "required": ["delta"],
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "properties": {
        "delta": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "title": "Delta",
            "type": "object",
            "required": ["service", "action"],
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "properties": {
              "service": { "type": "string" },
              "action": { "type": "string" },
              "attributes": {
                "anyOf": [
                  { "$ref": "#/definitions/DeltaAttributes_FOO" },
                  { "$ref": "#/definitions/DeltaAttributes_BAR" }
                ]
              }
            },
            "oneOf": [
              {
                "properties": { "service": { "const": "FOO" } },
                "attributes": {
                  "$ref": "#/definitions/DeltaAttributes_FOO"
                }
              },
              {
                "properties": { "service": { "const": "BAR" } },
                "attributes": {
                  "$ref": "#/definitions/DeltaAttributes_BAR"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },

    "DeltaAttributes_FOO": {
      "title": "DeltaAttributes_FOO",
      "type": "object",
      "required": ["foo_1", "foo_2"],
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "properties": {
        "foo_1": { "type": "string" },
        "foo_2": { "type": "string" }
      }
    },

    "DeltaAttributes_BAR": {
      "title": "DeltaAttributes_BAR",
      "type": "object",
      "required": ["bar_1"],
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "properties": {
        "bar_1": { "type": "string" }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And the JSON file I use to test it against:

```json
{
  "delta": [
    {
      "service": "FOO",
      "action": "someAction",
      "attributes": {
        "foo_1": "someValue",
        "foo_2": "anotherValue"
      }
    },
    {
      "service": "BAR",
      "action": "anotherAction",
      "attributes": {
        "bar_1": "value2"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

So far so good. I use https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/ to test it and everything works fine.

**BUT**, whenever I try to test the error output I don't have the expected behavior. If you try to remove, say the `foo_1` attribute from the test JSON file, the validator outputs an error saying `DeltaAttributes_FOO` lacks an attribute (which is the expected behavior) **AND** two other errors regarding DeltaAttributes_BAR (in this example: `Property 'foo_2' has not been defined and the schema does not allow additional properties` and `Required properties are missing from object: bar_1`).

I can't figure out why this behavior is happening considering the use of `oneOf` in the JSON schema which (if I understood correctly) is another way of writing `if..then..else` (which I don't use because in the real schema there are dozens of `attributes` to manage considering the `service` value).

Thanks in advance to anyone willing to dive into this!

Comment: a very relevant post for error output https://json-schema.org/blog/posts/interpreting-output